# Using Delphi to interact with an asp.net mvc 3 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, delphi, rest

I created a simple mvc3 site with a home controller with these actions.

```
public JsonResult Param(string id)
        {
            string upper = String.Concat(id, "ff");
            return Json(upper);
        }
        public ContentResult Param2(string id)
        {
            string upper = String.Concat(id, "ff");
            return Content( upper);
        }
        public JsonResult Param3(string id)
        {
            string upper = String.Concat(id, "ff");
            io gg = new io();
            gg.IOName = upper;
            return Json(gg);
        }
    }
    public class io
    {
         public string IOName {get;set;}
    }
```

I am using Delphi XE and the IPworks that came with it.
 Problem #1. No matter what I do I cannot send the post data. I set a breakpoint on the functions. So id is always null.

So these work (for posting data only) for any url.

```
 Json1.Get('http://localhost:1257/home/Param?id=ss');
REST1.Get('http://localhost:1257/home/Param2?id=kk');
```

But these DO NOT work (for posting data only) for any url.

```
REST1.PostData :='id=110559%2C102%2C0%2C0';
REST1.POST('http://localhost:1257/home/Param2');
```

or

```
json1.PostData:='id=110';
Json1.post('http://localhost:1257/home/Param');
```

but this works for posting

```
Webform.AddFormVar('id', '110559%2C102%2C0%2C0');
  Webform.SubmitTo('http://localhost:1257/home/Param2');
```

SO How am I formatting my parameters wrong????
Also I *Never* get the  variable gg formatted in a JSON way. Either blank or an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET requests are disabled by default for actions returning JSON. You can enable them like this:

```
return Json(upper, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: thanks but abut about getting the postdata into the id for posts. Also there is no json formatted value for the posts as well but thanks

Comment: @Joe, what about them? Did you use Fiddler to see the exact request being sent? Feel free to show it here so that we can help you.

Comment: I did it in chrome.  And these calls on the website were made by JQuery ajax so the data was {id: 44,55,9} to be posted.

Comment: @Joe, oh, i see, you are sending a JSON request. In this case you need to set the `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Comment: i had to unmark this as the answer because your stuff works for the test site. it does not for the live site. I made the calls all the same. same attributes same code on client content type and all. I knew I tried this before to no avail. Why would the app website be different?? I cannot post parameters period even though it works on sample site.